# Should I take Windows Server 2016 offline when applying MS updates?

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update

I know I should apply updates in an appropriate time window but is the server still fully operational while it is being patched?

I also realize that all patches may not take effect until the server is restarted, but is the server in fully functional state during the updates?

Is possible that patching may "lock" certain services while patched so they become unusable during that period?

Should I take the server offline while it it being patched to ensure nothing connects to it while being patched?